# How to save image in user defaults programmatically

Tags: swift

Hi i have a imageview and a button underneath which is called upload. When the user clicks on the button upload they can access there gallery and choose an image to set to the image view. When i close the app the image that has been set keeps disappearing. I was wondering i would have to use user defaults to save the image locally but i am not sure how to do this. I have provided my code down below.

image

```
var image:UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    image.backgroundColor = .black
    return image
}()
```

image picker controller

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let uploadedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
    {
 
        image.image = uploadedImage
        
        
        
    }else{
        
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016666/how-to-save-a-uiimage-to-documents-directory. Then you can save that directory URL to user defaults and access whenever.

Answer (score 1):

You can save any `UIImage` as `data` like:

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(uploadedImage.pngData()!, forKey: "uploadedImage")
```

And load like:

```
let loadedImage = UIImage(data: UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "uploadedImage")!)
```

<sub>But I highly recommend you to not save this image in the user defaults. Instead, use a file in the `Documents` directory</sub>

Comment: Thanks i might use core data to save the image

Comment: Just save your image to your application support directory. If your want the user to be able to access the image you can save it in the documents directory